# Making headers public in Xcode Framework

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, frameworks

Is there a **fast** way to make headers public when setting up a Framework in Xcode?  I always have to click through one by one, changing each one from private to public.  This irks me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Cmd-Click all header files you want
   to modify in the group tree.
2. Ctrl-Click them an choose "Set Role"
   -> "Public"

Comment: It's too bad there isn't a way to automatically do this.

Comment: Is this feature not available in latet XCode 3.2.5?